# Cursor and stored procedure optimisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization, database-cursor

The following stored proc has been written some time ago and now requires modification.

Unable to contact the original developer, I had a look. To me this proc seems over-complicated. Couldn't it be done with a straightforward UPDATE? Can anyone justify the use of CURSOR here?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [settle_Stage1]
    @settleBatch int
AS

DECLARE @refDate datetime;
DECLARE @dd int;
DECLARE @uid int;

DECLARE trans_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT uid, refDate FROM tblTransactions WHERE (settle IS NULL ) AND (state IN (  21, 31, 98, 99 ))
OPEN trans_cursor
FETCH FROM trans_cursor INTO @uid, @refDate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
    SET @dd = DATEDIFF( day, @refDate, getDate())
    IF ( @dd >= '1' )
      BEGIN
        UPDATE tblTransactions
        SET settle = @settleBatch WHERE uid = @uid
      END
    FETCH FROM trans_cursor INTO @uid, @refDate
   END  
CLOSE trans_cursor
DEALLOCATE trans_cursor
```

Comment: I agree with the others who have said that the original author didn't understand set based operations.  If the original author knew a good reason to use cursors, he also would have wrapped everything in a transaction and been looking for errors...

Comment: Roughly how many records would typically be involved in the update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are triggers involved that would blow up on multiple updated rows, then you would want to iterate.  But that would still not justify using an actual CURSOR.

Doing single updates would cause row locks and not page or table locks that a set based update could.  Since you're making the transactions smaller, the programmer could have been attempted to remove deadlocks which were caused by a large update.

**NOTE:** I am not advocating this method, I am only suggesting reasons.

Comment: Thanks. Is there no simpler way to force row locks?

Comment: Of course the proper refactoring in that case would involve fixing the trigger.

Comment: @Joel: You cannot force a row lock and use an set based update at the same time.  SQL Server chooses which to lock.  While you can NOLOCK a read, you can't set the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL on an update.

Comment: @Dan: You said you're not advocating this method but... if the developer wanted to avoid deadlocks then he did do the right thing...

Comment: @Joel: I wouldn't use a CURSOR, but iterate through a while loop if I needed too.  There are reasons that developers do things in a time crunch which other developers will look at and say, "WTF".  But there was a manager standing over them saying, "get it done."

Comment: Even seeing my own code written two years ago I often think WTF have I done ;-) pity he didn't add a comment to clarify the motivation for the cursor (but I also don't comment everything).

Answer (score 6):

You are right - this looks like "procedural SQL", from someone who probably doesn't get SQL and set operations.

And converting this to a set based query should help performance.

A cursor is not needed and is indeed over complicating the stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

Simply looking at it, I don't see any reason at all why this isn't done on a single UPDATE. Maybe (and its a maaaaaybe) if there are too many records to update, then this could be a reason. In any case, I would simply change it with:

```
UPDATE tblTransactions
SET settle = @settleBatch
WHERE settle IS NULL 
AND [state] IN (21, 31, 98, 99)
AND DATEDIFF( day, refDate, getDate()) >= 1
```

edited following @Martin Smith comment

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the comparison operator for the `datediff`

Comment: Also: `DATEDIFF` returns a numerical value - you shouldn't put single quotes around the `1` you're comparing to..... just use `DATEDIFF( day, refDate, getDate()) >= 1` ..

Comment: @marc_s - Yeap, I had that in my mind, and then just copy - pasted the condition as it was in the question. My bad

Answer (score 1):

If running one record at a time is too slow and a single update causes blocking and too much growth of the transaction log, the third alternative is to batch process. Use a set-based query, but run it through a loop of 1000 records at a time (you may have to experiement to find the optimum size of the batch).